# Modifier.imePadding() not applied for ModalBottomSheet Material3 Jetpack compose only API 29 and lower than it

Tags: android, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet, jetpack-compose-ime-padding

I have TextField inside BottomSheet and when I open the bottomSheet keyboard will cover the TextField which makes unable to see what I enter. When I use Modifier.imePadding() it will add the height of keyboard and scroll up but it works on only API/SDK over 29.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution for this issue?

Comment: I work around by different way. First get the ime height and if it's open or not and apply bottom padding ```    val isImeVisible = WindowInsets.isImeVisible
            val windowInsets = if(edgeToEdgeEnabled) WindowInsets(0) else
                BottomSheetDefaults.windowInsets.only(WindowInsetsSides.Top)

            val navigationBottomHeight = WindowInsets.systemBars.asPaddingValues().calculateBottomPadding()```